# Does everything in Marionnette have to be an object or collection

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am writing an app which will send orders to a remote server. I have a lot of the logic done now for setting up new orders. Items are added to a cart, cart totals are created and I am now ready to hit the server endpoint. At the moment, the REST API (which is being built by a separate team) needs me to:

- Send a new order request and receive a new order number
- Loop through my cart sending each item individually to the new order endpoint
- Send the order totals
- Send the payment options and amounts
- Return the final data as a receipt to the customer

I currently have
- A cart collection which contains item models
- A totals model

I am not looking for code particularly but could someone outline a method to send the data to the server. I'm trying to figure how to use collections and API URI endpoints to do this but don't have any precedent to follow. Would it be natural in a Marionette/Backbone app to use direct POST requests to the server using defferds and promises or is there a better approach?

I would appreciate any pointers in the right direction,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you wouldn't/shouldn't need to use direct POST requests when interacting with a REST API. Backbone models and collections are designed to interact with an API following this model out of the box.

If you define a collection as so:

```
var Items = Backbone.Collection.Extend({ url: '/items' });
var myItems = new Items();
myItems.fetch();
```

then when you call 'fetch' on the collection a GET request will be issued to your specified URL which will populate the collection with the models returned. You can add models to this collection which will fire the appropriate requests to the endpoint. eg. a POST. the default mappings are below for the above collection:

- create -> POST '/items'
- read -> GET '/items[/id]'
- update -> PUT '/items/id'
- delete -> DELETE '/items/id'

A lot of this is overridable and configurable so that you can fit into the API that your building against.